# Share OpenGL-Context between multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, opengl

[image]I have a `QGLWidget object` in `Qwidget::event` running in the main thread like this:

```
bool QRegistration::event(QEvent* e)
{
    QWidget::event(e);

    if (e->type() == QEvent::Show)
    {
        //Buffer rendering

        m_main_layout->addWidget(app_data->m_glWidget, 1, 1);
        m_main_layout->addWidget(app_data->m_glWidgetProjected, 1, 2);

        app_data->m_glWidget->repaint();
        app_data->m_glWidgetProjected->repaint();

        if (m_done)
            m_framework->statusBox->writeConfirmMessage("Registration Complete");
        else
            m_framework->statusBox->writeStatusMessage("Run Registration");
        QApplication::postEvent(m_framework, new QWidgetEvent(QWidgetEvent::FinishWorkingStep));

    }

    else if (e->type() == QEvent::Paint)
    {
        app_data->m_glWidgetLeft->update();
    }
}
```

Using the context of `m_glWidget` and `m_glWidgetProjected`I want to do some heavy Optimization in the background on a new `workerThread`:

```
for(;;)
{
    area Optimization::project3DModelAndDetectEdges(app_data->m_glWidget, app_data->m_glWidgetProjected);
}
```

with the following definition:

```
int Optimization::project3DModelAndDetectEdges(qGLWidget_input, qGLWidget_output)
{
    ...// update glWidget_input
    ... // project 3D-Model on the Image

    glWidget_output->renderModels();
    glWidget_output->endRendering();
    glWidget_output->repaint();
    ...
    return area;
}
```

This function is in the new thread `workerThread' in a long loop. I want to keep both of the widget updating with changes made to them on the workerThread.

My goal ist something just like the following picture, with the exception that I do not want to copy the contexts between the threads (Since they are huge).[image]
I condider using the pattern like what [Qt ducumentation (Threading)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qglwidget.html#updateGL) suggests. However I don't know how I could connect the signal and slots, so that it realizes my goal.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is...? Is the worker thread rendering straight onto the QGLWidget or into a FBO? What do you mean by "I do not want to copy the contexts" (I guess the "copy" in that diagram means blit the resulting image, not actually copy data)?

Comment: A QGLWidget can be made current just on the Thread which is created. So I decided to copy the widgets in the new thread, so that I be able to make them current on both of the threads. I should now somehow exchange the context of the widgets between the two threads. Sending the contexts is inefficient since there are huge. So? I have to use pointers to have shared contexts. But i don't know how to do that with connections, so that the contexts show on Window are allways compeletely rendered.

Comment: No, a QGLWidget can only be *created* on the GUI thread, but then one can call doneCurrent on the GUI thread, call makeCurrent on it from another thread, and paint on it using OpenGL. But I would recommend *against* this sort of magic. Use Qt 5 classes (QOpenGLWindow, QOpenGLContext, QOffscreenSurface) and do the management yourself as you need it.

Comment: Yes, doneCurrent! That was exactly what I first wanted to do. But for me that sounds to be the same thing as unthreated version. Because each time one thread has to wait for the other thread to be finished and only then can be made current. I'll study the classes you introduced. Thx.